# Changing css path in a view depending on the environment using DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using an external server to host my css/js files, I'm not using MVC's bundling.

I need to switch the absolute paths to my css files depending on the environment (dev/preprod/prod).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/main.css")">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mystaticserver.com/main.css")">
```

The root path is defined inside a config section that is injected.

What is the best way to access my config file from my view ?

Answer (score 0):

@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"]